# jQuery variable element syntax

Tags: jquery, syntax

I use the same element in my function several times.
For example:

```
var myElement = jQuery('#some_div_with_good_id');
var myChildren = jQuery('#some_div_with_good_id span');
```

So how I can optimize this code for shorten second variable?
I tried:

```
var myChildren = jQuery(myElement, 'span');
```

but this not works :(
I'm new in jQuery, so sorry if you think it is stupid question.

Comment: var myChildren = myElement.find('span');

Comment: It's the other way around -> `jQuery('span', myElement);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it the other way, `jQuery('span', myElement)` should work.

Comment: Thank you Steven! The decision was so close :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var children = $( element ).children( 'span' );
```

Comment: That's not equivalent to `jQuery('#some_div_with_good_id span')`, which finds descendant spans at all levels; `.children()` just finds immediate children.

Comment: Ah. Going by his variable name (myChildren), I figured he only wanted the children of that element.